# How to access json elements

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable soap which looks like this

```
{
  "soapenv:Head":{
      "title": "titleName"
  },
  "soapenv:Body":{
      "element1": "elementName"
  }
}
```

How can I access soapenv:Body? I am having Unexpected token : while trying

soap.soapenv:Body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an special char `:` in the key-name, you should use this:

```
soap["soapenv:Body"]
```

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a valid Javascript identifier.

Instead, you need to use indexer notation:

```
soap["soapenv:Body"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try soap `['soapenv:Body']` The key can't take special characters when using the `.` notation to access